# How can we set background image none with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I can't figure out I want when I press button set backgroundImage = none but I cant I was trying this my code;

My section

```js
var colorChanger = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
colorChanger.addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
  document.getElementById("home").style.backgroundImage = "none";
```

```css
#home {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1.5rem;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/200.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
```

```html
<section class="home" id="home">
  <div class="content">
    <h3>Who I am?</h3>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      <h2>My Education Process</h2>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
      <a href="About.html" class="btn">Read More...</a> <br><br></section>
</p>
```

also I was trying;

```
var colorChanger = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
colorChanger.addEventListener("click",function() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#000"; 
  document.getElementById("home").style.backgroundImage = null;
```

both don't work.
where am i doing wrong?

Comment: First thing you need to do whenever any script doesn't do what you expect is check the console in the browser's developer tools for any errors possibly shown there. **Pls do that now and edit the error you see into this question.**

Comment: You should avoid to use `.style` function in JS in 2021. The modern approach is to use `.classList` +
 `.add('class-name')` , `.remove('class-name')` or `.toggle('class-name')` to apply changes through CSS.
 This causes far less issues incl. possible specificity weight issues. Also you sholudnt use `getElementsByTagName` anymore but `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll`

Comment: @tacoshy Although what you point out is correct, it probably doesn't help OP at their point of learning. His problem here is simply a syntax error.

Comment: @connexo well if he would apply a CSS class to remove the background image (given specificty weight) then it should help.

Comment: Home .html:53 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
    at Home.html:53    script.js:53 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at script.js:53
(anonymous) @ script.js:53

Comment: If you click on that line pointed out in the error message, which line exactly does it take you to?

Comment: Also, reload the page and click the "run snippet" button in your question. You'll see the syntax error you made.

Comment: @tacoshy **Never** fix any errors in the question when editing questions. This renders both the question and potentially correct answers useless. I've rolled back our edit since you fixed one of the errors in OP's 2nd attempt shown.

Comment: @connexo the scope of the question was not changed at all. The issues are not caused by a misplaced `</p>` closing tag. The issue showed fine with the snippet. Frankly a [repro]  would already demonstrate the variaty of issues with the code.

Comment: @tacoshy The snippet was not the problem in your edit. It was that you added the missing closing `}` in OP's second attempt shown.

Comment: @connexo in whichc ase an edit would have been mroe apporpiate then a rollback! But even with the closign tag, the issue remains the same. The tags are surely not missing but due to a cut down piece of code.

Comment: @tacoshy I'm not here to fix mistakes others make while editing; rolling back was the shortest path to fixing the problem your edit caused. Please feel free to edit again. Make sure to never fix any problems with any code other than fixing code formatting for readability.

Comment: @tacoshy do you have a reference for the statement that getElementsByTagName should  not be used. I ask because some (though luckily very few) old browser versions can use it while they cannot use querySelector... Also there are occasions in which style needs to be used so your statement seems a bit too general.

Comment: @AHaworth , it is actually very (to) general. Giving a detailed answer would just blow the frame for SO. I expect that someone knowing the difference in detail, also know when to use the "old" getElementsByTagName.

Answer (score 0):

1. I added a class `#home.bg-none` that has a heigher specificty weight then a normal ID. Otherwise we would have a specificty weight issue because an ID has a heigher weight then a class.
2. I added the propery and value `background-image: none;` to that class aswell as your intended `background-color` change.
3. I used in JS: `classList.add('class-name')` to apply the class to the section on a button click.

```js
function bgChange() {
  var sectionHome = document.querySelector('#home'); 
  sectionHome.classList.add('bg-none');
}
```

```css
/* css changes */
#home.bg-none {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
}



/* original CSS, changed ID to class */
#home {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1.5rem;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/200.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}


/* for demonstrations purpose only */
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#home {
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 3em;
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<section id="home" class="home">Test-Section</section>

<button onclick="bgChange()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use removeAttribute() and  setAttribute()
[here is an example for you](https://codepen.io/gulsenkeskin/pen/PoKjNBX)

```
var colorChanger = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];

colorChanger.onclick = function(){
document.getElementById("home").removeAttribute("class");
document.getElementById("home").setAttribute("class", "homecss"); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function removeBG(){
              event.preventDefault();

            document.getElementById("home").style.background = "none";
        }
```

```css
#home{
          display: flex;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
          gap:1.5rem;
          min-height: 100vh;
          align-items: center;
          background-image: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/YID679VxCfxmJqd8YiF-E43a5XxxTC7R3dE5iGScHPUbMnDvG9-qAG1PEp9Qrl09pmQIzujGCEIpyAyQb25DWosqSTXPoRGcwihJ3wf-NCk4Mhunlwod-EOsoiRMgNuvzh7_if3sfitCBi4LBoVP8qPB);
          
          background-size: cover;
          background-position: center;
        }
```

```html
<section class="home" id="home"  > <div class="content">
    <h3>Who I am?</h3>
    <p>
       Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        <h2>My Education Process</h2>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
        <a href="about.html" class="btn" onclick="removeBG()">Read More...</a> <br><br></section>
```

Comment: Code only answers are considered low quality. Without sufficient explaination, your answer is hard to understand.
If the Op can't udnerstand your answer, then he also wont be able to reproduce your possible solution. As such it 
would be worthless to him/her. Please add a suficient explaination of your possible solution.